Would human-shaped sperm cells work?
After looking at videos of sperm cells, they reminded me of someone swimming. I've decided this was a neat idea for me to integrate in my worldbuilding.
For lore reasons, I have a group of people with human sperm cells that don't look like tadpoles but this albeit thinner below the head:

It has everything it needs in creating a human baby. It moves by waving its appendages in a butterfly stroke like a professional swimmer.
Can this work? After a bit of research, the tadpole shape seems most optimized for swimming. However, I haven't found any indications of human-shaped sperm cells being unviable or impossible.

Yes, multi-flagellate sperm cells exist; for example, all plants which have motile sperm cells (mosses, ferns and allies, Ginkgo, cycads) have multi-flagellate sperm cells.

Butterfly works by putting the return stroke of the arms out of the water so that you don't have water resistance. Fully underwater it doesn't gain you anything.

Human bodies are very bad at moving efficiently through liquids. Yes, we can swim, but we can often not cover any appreciable distance any faster than we can walk. The current world record for 100 meter long-course breast stroke works out to about 6.3 km/h, which is roughly equivalent to a fast walk, and that was a sprinting pace using all the muscles of the body. Other strokes may go faster, but they all rely on part of the stroke happening out of the water and thus simply won’t work here. In comparison, a dolphin can manage 32 km/h over long distances trivially, and sprint much faster.

There's a Woody Allen movie in which he plays a spermatozoon.

For small objects in water the viscosity of water is very high. Which greatly constrains how small things can move. What works at macro level doesn't usually work a t micro level and vice versa.

One of the major concerns I have is what exactly you mean by "appendages". Single cellular organisms primarily move using either flagella, longer whip-like tails, or cilia, smaller, numerous hair-like structures on their cell wall.
Cells can also move via other methods such as pseudo-pods, but those are generally far slower. It would also greatly reduce the chances of sperm reaching the egg, if not make it entirely implausible.
Assuming that the genetic material is held in the head, what purpose do the other appendages serve? If they were simply flagella, like some other answers are assuming, then your sperm would not end up human-shaped. The flagella would trail behind the sperm during movement regardless of the angle of attachment. They would also be significantly less effective at propelling the sperm.
If the appendages are actual parts of the cell containing cytoplasm, then the sperm would constantly have to exert energy or carry some sort of solid structure to help it maintain its shape. Both would make it much harder to reach the egg. If you are committed to the human shape, the appendages would almost definitely be covered by cilia so they can make some contribution to propulsion.
To explain this further in-universe, perhaps create some biological differences in female that make it significantly easier for sperm to reach the egg. Additionally, it would likely be much harder to conceive. In fact, maybe the people in your world depend entirely on artificial or otherwise assisted insemination.
Its difficult to conclude that it would be impossible, because surely there is some combination of organic material that could produce a single-cellular organism of human shape that can successfully reach the egg. However, it would be extremely inefficient if not entirely implausible that even with genetic engineering we could produce viable sperm of this shape. It would be much easier to make completely sweeping genetic changes on a macro-scale.
However, if you wanted to go another route, perhaps instead of simply reaching the egg, sperm face many perils and must survive for an extended period, collecting food and slowly making their way to the egg. Being expected to gather energy and survive for an extended period moves the purpose of sperm away from a mad sprint which greatly expands the plausible design space. You would need to come up with an explanation for why the female reproductive system has become so hostile towards sperm though.

Female reproductive systems being "hostile" to sperm cells is rather unsurprising from an evolutionary perspective. It's a filter mechanism to only allow sperm cells that satisfy certain criteria to reach the egg.

You're right about the filter. Though I would say it's difficult for sperm to be the first to reach the egg, I wouldn't say the environment is hostile for any genetically healthy sperm. The level of "hostility" that would encourage sperm to consume energy and adapt in this manner goes far beyond anything that would be useful for ensuring genetic fitness.


I haven't found any indications of human-shaped sperm cells being unviable or impossible

Evolution doesn't write papers to document why certain things do not work. If every single species using sexual reproduction uses flagellated sperm cells to accomplish the task, it means that other configuration are, to put it mildly, not better than it to achieve the goal. And evolution is a harsh mistress when it comes to cutting out inefficiencies.
That said, if there is anything that all the horror and thriller movies get right when involving fishes or other swimming creatures, is that humans are terrible swimmers. Our records in the swimming pool would make dolphins, crocs, sharks and company laugh at us. (dolphins might actually already been doing that)
Sure, we can swim, but we are far from being among the best. The only thing where we really excel is endurance running. If you can concoct some reproductive mechanisms where sperms have to run on long distances, there the human shape might help.

And even there, as I understand things, our excellence at endurance running has far less to do with musculature and body shape, instead being mostly about an extraordinary ability to shed waste heat.

“Evolution doesn't write papers to document why certain things do not work.” and “(dolphins might actually already been doing that)” made my day!

Our records in the swimming pool are also ridiculed by land animals like elephants or polar bears.

If every species is using strategy A, it means superior strategy is low probability shuffling of the deck. It is possible to have a local maxima that is very hard to get away from once found, but from a less locked starting point there may be many such maxima.

"If every single species using sexual reproduction uses flagellated sperm cells to accomplish the task [...]". It's worth pointing out then that there are taxa with aflagellate sperm. This tends to occur in species with highly monandrous mating systems. Check out: How the sperm lost its tail: the evolution of aflagellate sperm.

Sure, sperm like this could work.  The head would be the nucleus, the body would contain the mitochondria, and the arms and legs would be flagella.
However, such a sperm with four flagella would use energy at a much greater rate than singly-flagellated sperm, without any great increase in speed.  They might outrun regular sperm for a little while, then they would run out of energy and stop, and be overtaken by the regular sperm.
Just because something could work doesn't mean that it will work well.  When it comes to sperm, it's a long race to the egg, and only the sperm that are fastest over that distance will win.  Those that don't make the distance don't get to pass on their genes for their anthropomorphic shape.

Good answer… if we assume swimming all the way. I’m thinking maybe there could be a section of the course to be out of fluid, where climbing/running is advantageous? Just brainstorming here.

@SRM That's not how flagella work.  They're a single-environment engine: fluid-only.

"[...] only the sperm that are fastest over that distance will win" this is a myth. Misconceptions about Conception and Other Fallacies: Historical Bias in Reproductive Biology covers the issues with this framing extensively in both human and non-human conception. I recommend giving it a read, it expresses it better than I could.
